# Extract image from Google Sheets using google script

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has a JPG image embedded.  I would like to be able to extract this image using a google script.

My overall goal is to create a google script that copies sheet cell data to a new spreadsheet.  I would also like to extract the image attached to the original sheet and attach it to the new spreadsheet.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this at all.  I can extract sheets, columns, cells, etc.  But I don't see any way to identify or extract the JPG that is embedded in the sheet itself.
         
I have done google searches (and stack overflow searches)  
      
Here is how it can be extracted manually:
https://www.softwarehow.com/extract-google-docs-images/
    
However, that solution is not able to be scripted.

Comment: The addon is written in Apps Script, so it isn't impossible. Doing it without a user interaction may be the difficult part.